# Match Country in String, split based on result

Tags: php, regex, split

I have a CSV file with one of the fields holding state/country info, formatted like:
"Florida United States" or "Alberta Canada" or "Wellington New Zealand" - not comma or tab delimited between them, simply space delimited.

I have an array of all the potential countries as well.

What I am looking for, is a solution that, in a loop, I can split the State and Country to different variables, based on matching the country in the $countryarray that I have something like:

```
$countryarray=array("United States","Canada","New Zealand");
$userfield="Wellington New Zealand");
$somefunction=(match "New Zealand", extract into $country, the rest into $state)
```

Split won't do it straight up - because many of the countries AND states have spaces, but the original data set concatenated the state and country together with just a space...

TIA!

Comment: I don't see a trivial solution, but split, create a string that's just the last word, check the country array, and keep adding previous words in the array until you get a match. You could also create an array of regexs that end in elements of countryarray and loop through each to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a fan of the RegEx method that @Mike Morton mentioned. You can take an array of countries, implode them using the `|` which is a RegEx `OR`, and use that as an "ends with one of these" pattern.

Below I've come up with two ways to do this, a simple way and an arguably overly complicated way that does some extra escaping. To illustrate what that escaping does I've added a fake country called `Country XYZ (formally ABC)`.

Here's the sample data that works with both methods, as well as a helper function that actually does the matching and echoing. The RegEx does named-capturing, too, which makes things really easy to deal with.

```php
// Sample data
$data = [
    'Wellington New Zealand',
    'Florida United States of America',
    'Quebec Canada',
    'Something Country XYZ (formally ABC)',
];

// Array of all possible countries
$countries = [
    'United States of America',
    'Canada',
    'New Zealand',
    'Country XYZ (formally ABC)',
];

// The begining and ending pattern delimiter for the RegEx
$delim = '/';

function matchAndShowData(array $data, array $countries, string $delim, string $countryParts): void
{
    $pattern = "^(?<region>.*?) (?<country>$countryParts)$";
    
    foreach($data as $d) {
        if(preg_match($delim . $pattern . $delim, $d, $matches)){
            echo sprintf('%1$s, %2$s', $matches['region'], $matches['country']), PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            echo 'NO MATCH: ' . $d, PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

### Option 1

The first option is a naïve implode. This method, however, will not find the country that includes parentheses.

```php
matchAndShowData($data, $countries, $delim, implode('|', $countries));
```

#### Output

```
Wellington, New Zealand
Florida, United States of America
Quebec, Canada
NO MATCH: Something Country XYZ (formally ABC)
```

### Option 2

The second option applies proper RegEx quoting of the countries, just in case they have special characters. If you are 100% certain you don't have any, this is overkill, but I personally have learned, after way too many hours of debugging, to just always quote, just in case.

```php
$patternParts = array_map(fn(string $country) => preg_quote($country, $delim), $countries);

// Implode the cleaned countries using the RegEx pipe operator which means "OR"
matchAndShowData($data, $countries, $delim, implode('|', $patternParts));
```

#### Output

```
Wellington, New Zealand
Florida, United States of America
Quebec, Canada
Something, Country XYZ (formally ABC)
```

### Note

If you don't expect your list of countries to change often you can `echo` the pattern out and then just bake that into your code which will probably shave a couple of milliseconds of execution, which in a tight loop might be worth it.

### Demo

You can see a demo of this here: https://3v4l.org/CaNRZ

Answer (score 0):

- Prepare the array of countries for use in a regular expression with `preg_quote()`.
- Build a regex pattern that will match a space followed by one of the country values then the end of the string.  A lookahead (`(?= ... )`) is used to ensure that those matched characters are not consumed/destroyed while exploding.
- Save the 2-element returned array from `preg_split()` to the output array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7pjIL))

```
$branches = array_map(fn($country) => preg_quote($country, '/'), $countries);

$result = [];
foreach ($data as $string) {
    $result[] = preg_split('/ (?=(?:' . implode('|', $branches) . ')$)/', $string);
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Wellington',
    1 => 'New Zealand',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Florida',
    1 => 'United States of America',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Quebec',
    1 => 'Canada',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Something',
    1 => 'Country XYZ (formally ABC)',
  ),
)
```

Note that if an item/row in the result array only has one element, then you know that the attempted split failed to match the country substring.

I use this same technique when splitting street name and street type (when things like "First Street North" (a multi-word street type)) happens.